# Handle Choose Account PopUp in Appium

Tags: selenium, automation, appium, appium-android

Hey there is an app called Raaga when i open the app it shows me an popup 
that says
 choose an account For Raaga in which i want to just ignore that popup
can you tell me how can i do that

More about that pop: That is the similar type of the popup that is shown us when we open the playstore and get a popup to select the username

Comment: Can you add the screenshot or code what you have tried.

Comment: Try printing the pages source when that popup appears. There should be an Id associated with it and then you can click on the dismiss button

Comment: can you tell me how can i get the id of the that popup

Comment: @lovesoni if you get the page source you can see the Id in there. https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/commands/session/source.md